# Multiple 404 error pages in nginx

Tags: nginx

I am running nginx server. I want to serve a custom error page for a particular request only. For-example for request

```
http://localhost/abc1 & http://localhost/abc2
```

if these pages are not there I want to serve a custom error page. This custom error page should appear only for above two mentioned links, rest of the page errors can show the default error page. I have tried different configuration but nothing seems to work. Thoughts

Regards,
Farrukh Arshad.

Comment: is there other files inside those directories that u dont want to show 404? like `http://localhost/abc2/image.jpg` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer. The trick is you have to define error_page explicitly for all those special locations. Here is the configuration which worked for me.

```
location / {
    root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
}

location /abc1.html {
    root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    error_page 404 /special_error.html;
}
location /abc2.html {
    root   /var/www/nginx-default;
    error_page 404 /special_error2.html;
}
```

I am not good with nginx, but I have noticed it depends on the search pattern you give in "location" tag. I have tried different things and those failed . Forexample the above rules will ONLY work for

```
http://localhost/abc1.html
```

and fail for

```
http://localhost/abc1
```

so your "location" search pattern should be good if you want to cover second case. Probably some nginx guru can shed some more light on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Your answer is quite correct, but as you said, you only defined them for the html's, remove the extension and it should work for the whole directory, no need to repeat the root, just define it in the server block scope

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root   /var/www/nginx-default;

    location /abc1 {        
        error_page 404 /special_error.html;
    }

    location /abc2 {
        error_page 404 /special_error2.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: If I define this rule (along with the root directive) for directory this does not work as expected. When the directory abc1 is there and I try to access the directory I receive 403 Forbidden Error. If directory 403 is not there I got good error page (special_error.html). Please also note that if I do not add this rule for directory, I can access my directory when it is there. My directory is a symlink. Nginx is running with user root (the site is  a web admin for embedded device, so no worries with root). Thoughts.

Comment: do you want it to do a 404 no matter what ?

Comment: My Use case. I have nginx running on an embedded device. What I want is when I insert a USB Pen Drive, I want to access it via Nginx. I create a symlink in the root of nginx at abc1 pointing to mounted path of USB Pen drive. This part is complete and working good. if there is no USB drive, there will be no symlink hence location abc1 will be invalid, I want to show custom 404 page, please insert USB Drive. So when I apply above mentioned rule I see the behavior I have mentioned in my previous comment. Point is I am running nginx as user "root" then why it says 403 Forbidden.

Comment: can you please check the error log and tell me what it says about this 403, also please describe the content of the USB, is it HTML files, or folders, and the shape of the URL you will use to access the USB

Comment: Ok, found the issue. I need to add autoindex on; in the abc1. Since it is a directory and does not contain index.html. Without autoindex option you should be getting Error 403 for requests that end with / on directories that do not have an index.html file. With this option you should be getting a simple listing. Anyways thanks for your time.

Comment: I thought u didn't want to show the directory, but ok, as long as you got it fixed that's good